# CSS pseudo class to display background color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have three html pages that can be visited through  tags that are on the navbar
So, there is not a main layout that shares the same navbar. Each page has its own HTML5 but they share the *same CSS file*

When a certain page is getting visited, its page on the navbar has a class "active " (See below)

navbar at the index.html

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html" class = "active">Home</a>
    <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
    <a href="history.html">History</a>
    <a href="http://......" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
</nav>
```

navbar at the team.html

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="team.html" class = "active">Teams</a>
    <a href="history.html">History</a>
    <a href="http:...." target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
</nav>
```

and so on for the history page

Each  tag has been given CSS rules to be displayed like a button. (no bootstrap used)

What I tried to do is whenever I am on a certain page I want the  tag to have a white background color. In order for the visitor to know which page is currently open.

Finally I have configured it with the following CSS rule

**Solution**

```
.active{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**Initially** i tried to do it by using pseudo-class

**1)**

```
nav a:active{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**2)**

```
nav a:active:before{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**3)**

```
nav a:active:after{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Also used `:target` pseudo class but did not work.

For those that marked 1, 2, 3 and did not work, i tried it as I read the documentation and having seen a proposed solution on fiddle.

*Can someone tell me what is the difference between the solution that worked and the others that I tried allong with `:target` and did not work?*

Comment: The difference is the .active class worked, but the :active pseudo did not.

Comment: Ye, and I am trying to understand why

Comment: The element has the active class so you have to use that. Active pseudo has to do with the state of the object in the dom when the user clicks it, so you can style this, but not its non clicked state: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: yes i read it that's why regarding the state of the object i tried to use `:target` but again it didn't work

Comment: You're styling the wrong thing, the class gets the style no matter what the pseudo, or state, of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have three pages that each one has its own HTML code, the way you solved it is one that you could do it, elsewhere in order to use `:target` you had to move as follow
Specify on each `<a>` an id and that id to be lace also at the end of the href.
See bellow

```
<div class="side_col">

<a href="#sl1">
  <div id="sl1" class="side_link">Accounts
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#sl2">
  <div id="sl2" class="side_link">Newsletter
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#sl3">
  <div id="sl3" class="side_link">Operator
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#l4">
<a href="#sl4">
  <div id="sl4" class="side_link">Invoice
  </div>
</a>
</a>
```

And the CSS

`#sl1:target:before, #sl2:target:before, #sl3:target:before, #sl4:target:before { background-color: #24BDE9; }`

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` pseudo-class is only applied to an element while it is considered to be active: for an anchor, that is typically for the time from when you click your mouse button on it until you release your mouse button. That is not a particularly long time!

Taking a look at your example, it would work like this:

1. User begins clicking the Home link. Their mouse button depresses, and that link becomes `:active`. Your CSS using the `:active` pseudo-class in a rule applies to it.
2. The user releases the mouse button. That link is no longer `:active` and your CSS using the pseudo-class stops applying.
3. Page navigation happens. That link that was `:active` certainly isn't any more! This is when your class would take over and you achieve that effect that you want.

`:active` has a very short duration tied literally to the element being interacted with by the user: they are making it `:active` by clicking on it and not releasing their mouse button. In your case, that interaction is brief and will not carry over during page navigation.

This is why using a class works: that class is there when the page loads, will always stay there (unless you change it programmatically), and gives you a way to apply your CSS like you want.

EDIT to answer a question on `:target` below.

`:target` matches an element by ID to the URL fragment. In your example, you aren't using IDs, nor are you using URL fragments, so there is nothing that would be considered a `:target`.

`:target` could work with a structure like this below, but it's going a long way to solve a problem best solved by classNames:

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html#home" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="teams.html#teams" id="teams">Teams</a>
    <a href="history.html#history" id="history>History</a>
</nav>
```

In the example above, each link has a fragment and an element with the ID matching the fragment (`#home` and the first nav item's ID, for example). In that case, you would have an element that would be considered a `:target`.

Comment: because as you said "has a very short duration tied", that also passed from my mind that's why i tried the same but instead of using `:active` i tried to use `:target` and `:target:before` and also `:target:after` but again it did not work

Comment: Added an explanation above.

Comment: Indeed the example that I saw was used with ID but I thought it could be also be done by using directly the elements. So, I missed that difference that is being used only with IDs and needs to have fragment.

In that HTML example as I said each page has its own HTML5 code but shares the same CSS file.

If I had a common Layout that the navbar was shareable among all pages if there was the same class to all `<a>` tags I assume that all `<a>` tags would be enabled when a certain page  would be active.

*What solution would be optimum for that situation in order to achieve the same result?*

Answer (score 0):

You used `nav a:active{...`, but `active` is the *class*, so your selector has to be `nav a.active{...` instead. (dot, not colon)

Comment: I tried to use the pseudo class `:active` . However at the same example by coincidence the class it is also called `.active`

Comment: But `:active` is something completely different: The `:active` pseudo class status is only "active" during the very short time between a link is clicked and the linked page is loaded, which often happens so fast that you don't see it at all. It definitely has nothing to do with which page is currently displayed.

Comment: yes exactly, that's why later on i tried to use the `:target` pseudo class but again didn't work.

Comment: That's again something else: "The :target pseudo-class can be used to highlight the portion of a page that has been linked to from a table of contents." --> from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Answer (score 0):

```
nav a.active { ... }
```

The only difference is saying `a.active` instead of `a:active` due to the fact that `.active` is a class. You can check out this [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_vertical.asp):  (scroll down a bit to where it says "Active/Current Navigation Link")

Hopefully this helped!

Comment: this is how I resolved it.

But If I had a common Layout that the navbar was shareable among all pages if there was the same class to all <a> tags I assume that all <a> tags would be enabled when a certain page would be active. What solution would you recommend to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you're saying that if you were to set all of the code to `class='active'`, then yes, all of them would be highlighted white. Just change your `class='active'` to the active link for that page (e.g., on the 'team' page set **only** the team link as active). I'm not really sure I understand your question, could you clarify?

Comment: As a further question on my initial question, I am asking what would be the solution to achieve the same result if there was a common layout that would be shared among all pages. Currently each page has its own HTML code and navbar

Comment: You only need 1 css stylesheet. You're going to have to recreate the navbar on every page, there is no work around for that afaik.